# Not getting desired output in electron app but getting the same in node CLI using same Nodejs file

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to display docker container logs in my electron app. I'm using dockerode API.I can't find the command in dockerode so i used node-cmd to execute in CLI and get the output. But it is working only in NodeJs command line but the same in electron comes with extra characters like the image. Any help would be appreciated.

Node js file:

```js
var Docker = require('dockerode')
var docker = new Docker({ host:'127.0.0.1',port:2375});
//festive_jepsen is container name.
//using alert for electron and console for nodejs CLI

var cnt='festive_jepsen';
var cmd=require('node-cmd');
function onl()
{
    cmd.get(
        'docker logs '+cnt,
        function(err, data, stderr){
            alert(data);
            //console.log(data);
        }
    );
}
```

[This is the input i want and it is executing perfectly in nodejs CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQuYy.png)

[This is how the output is in Electron app if i use the same code and alert box instead of console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okFM5.png)

Comment: Those look like ANSI color codes. The console is using them to change the text color but the alert dialog doesn't know what to do with them.

Comment: @takteek Or ANSI spaces, since the white lines also have different codes in them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ansi-to-html API to convert the colored text .
It works perfectly now.

Node js file:

`var Convert = require('ansi-to-html');
var convert = new Convert();
Converted_data = convert.toHtml(data); //data is the string with colored text`